# putting label for DropDownlist

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to put label in front of *DropdownList* but *dropdownlist* comes in next line. I tried option given on this blog but not found solution.

Here is simple code i am using:

Group:

```html
<div>
    <div style="margin-top: 2%; "; id='jqxWidget' ;>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to forget to add your code. Please add the code here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that div is a **block level** element. Thats the reason you see it in the next line.. Instead of div use a label element to solve your problem..

Or you can use div's and give it a float:left property..

Try this

```
<div style="width:300px;">
    <div style="width:100px; float:left">
        <span> jQWidgets DropDown : </span>
     </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 2%;width:250px; float:left;" id='jqxWidget'>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should work for you. I have included inline styles in the code which is a bad practice.. Try assigning class names instead..

Comment: By putting the label element is affecting its position on page .